# Organizing key value pairs value in comma separated fashion

Tags: javascript

I have two array like this:

```js
var actval = [
  0: "3"
  1: "22-Nov-2018 15:32:36 IST"
  2: "22-Nov-2018 15:32:40 IST"
  3: "3"
  4: "22-Nov-2018 15:32:36 IST"
  5: "22-Nov-2018 15:32:40 IST"
  6: "3"
  7: "22-Nov-2018 15:32:36 IST"
  8: "22-Nov-2018 15:32:40 IST"
]

var id = [
  0: "STATUS"
  1: "STARTTIME"
  2: "ENDTIME"
  3: "STATUS"
  4: "STARTTIME"
  5: "ENDTIME"
  6: "STATUS"
  7: "STARTTIME"
  8: "ENDTIME"
]
```

What I want to do is make a final array which would have keys as `STATUS`, `STARTTIME`, `ENDTIME` and each of the keys can have multiple values like this:

```js
finalarray = [
  STATUS: ["3", "3", "3"]
  STARTTIME: ["22-Nov-2018 15:32:36 IST", "22-Nov-2018 15:32:36 IST", "22-Nov-2018 15:32:36 IST"]
  ENDTIME: ["22-Nov-2018 15:32:40 IST", "22-Nov-2018 15:32:40 IST", "22-Nov-2018 15:32:40 IST"]
]
```

For this I have tried this approach :

```js
for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  currentKey = id[i];
  currentVal = actval[i];
  result[currentKey] = currentVal;
}
```

but it only gives me one value for each key not every value:

How can i get the each value in that array linked to that key?

Comment: `actval` and `id` are not arrays, you are using them like objects.

Comment: First get to know [object vs array](https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html) and reframe the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** **Just adding one check in your code**

try this:

```
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  let currentKey = id[i];
  let currentVal = actval[i];
  if(result[currentKey])    
      result[currentKey] = [...result[currentKey],currentVal];
  else
    result[currentKey] = [currentVal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming actval is array not object:

```
finalobject = {
STATUS: actval.filter(e=>e.length===1),
STARTTIME: actval.filter((e, i)=>i%3).filter((e, i)=>i%2===0),
ENDTIME: actval.filter((e, i)=>i%3).filter((e, i)=>i%2!==0),
};
```

I will update question, when you will clarify some things and change this "arrays" to objects.

Answer (score 0):

If actval always look like that and you want to extract the top 3 values you could just do a `shift()` something like this.

```
var final = {STATUS: [], STARTTIME:[], ENDTIME:[]};
for (let i=0; actval.length > i; i++) {

    final.STATUS.push( actval.shift() );

    final.STARTTIME.push( actval.shift() );

    final.ENDTIME.push( actval.shift() );

}
```

What you are doing is just writing over the same array value with =.

You are always doing result['key'] = 'value';